# Error en consulta de JavaScrip con API REST

Tags: javascript

Estoy accediendo a una api con javascript, pero al momento de ejecutar el bloque de código, me aparece el siguiente error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "length", Data is undefined

Este es el códdigo que tengo:

```
function Get_Product(id)
{
fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    boddy: JSON.stringify({
        id: id
    }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then(function (reponse){
    if(reponse.ok)
    {
        return reponse.text;
    }
    else
    {
        return alert("Error");
    }

}).then(function(Data){
    for( i = 0; i < Data.length; i++)
        {
            let div = document.createElement("div");
            div.classList.add("card");
            let p = document.createElement("p");


            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = Data[i].url_image;

            p.innerHTML = Data[i].name;


            div.appendChild(img);
            div.appendChild(p);
            document.getElementById("content").appendChild(div);
        }
})}
```

No se si estoy usando mal al momento de mandar el dato, para que me regrese la consulta. Lo que quiero, es que cuando yo envío el id, me regresa los productos que son de esa categoría, pero ni siquiera llega al API.

Comment: Revisa bien qué hay en ese Data, quizá no sea un arreglo, y al hacerle un .length a un elemento que no es un arreglo te está dando el error

Comment: Quiero saber si estoy haciendo bien el código, porque si me mostraba los resultados si lo hago sin parametros

Comment: En teoría está bien, nada más es cuestión de ver qué está en la variable Data, pues ese error aparece cuando quieres hacer un .length a una variable indefinida

Answer (score 1):

No se suele enviar datos por body en una llamada GET,esto puede hacer que sea rejected. Podría ser un method post o un get pasando el id por query string.
Por otro lado en el primer then se está haciendo response.text, en caso de ser un texto lo recibido debería ser response.text(), aunque de acuerdo al resto del código en el primer then debería utilizar response.json().
Restaría confirmar en la documentación de la API como se le debe enviar el id.